# Probleme with as_flex_table with Rmardown and beamer

Tags: gtsummary, beamer

I use Rmardown with beamer.
Before the function as_flex_table and rmardown Beamer worked very well.
Now with the gtsummary_1.7.2 and rmarkdown_2.25 version, the follow code does not work anymore:

`your text`as_flex_table_ex1 <-
`trial %>% select(trt, age, grade) %>% tbl_summary(by = trt) %>% add_p()%>% as_flex_table(as_flex_table_ex1) as_flex_table_ex1`

I have a message error each time:

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate.

1
l.220 \end{frame}

Erreur : LaTeX failed to compile test_flextable_beaamer.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test_flextable_beaamer.log for more info.
Exécution arrêtée

But if i knit with word, or pdf document its works. Can someone helps me ?

Thanks a lot

I tried to do it with rmardown pdf (document), word, and its work, so for me it is not Latex the problem.

Comment: Please add a [mre]